# Локальный репозиторий

Tags: репозиторий

Господа знатоки, внимание вопрос:Научите ламера-новичка, как установить локальный репозиторий, чтоб с него могли обновляться клиентские машины (обновление должно происходить с ограничением скорости), а так же как научить апач обрабатывать символические ссылки. Используется операционка Alt linux 6-я платформа.

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте `Wiki Alt-Linux` про [создание локального репозитория](http://www.altlinux.org/APT_%D0%B2_ALT_Linux/CreateRepository)

Или [тут про создание локального репозитория](http://svictor.ru/lokalnyj-repozitorij-v-alt-linux-2) с помощью `Alterator` входящего в состав `Alt-Linux`

Надеюсь Вам не составит труда разобраться - там всё разложено по полочкам

;-)

Comment: Спасибо, ссылки весьма полезны, для общего развития.

Answer (score 1):

[Создание локального репозитория](http://www.altlinux.org/APT_%D0%B2_ALT_Linux/CreateRepository)

> Для создания репозитория достаточно создать правильную структуру директорий, разместить в ней rpm-пакеты и создать метаинформацию для APT.

Чтобы Apache отрабатывал символические ссылки есть опция FollowSymLinks

```
<Directory />    Options FollowSymLinks</Directory>
```

Comment: А поясните пожалуйста, куда вписывать данную опцию.